# fopen(NULL, "r") crashes as kernel __range_ok(NULL, 1) got true

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

When I open a NULL file in user space, our system(armv7 platform, based on linux kernel 3.2.16) will crash due to "unhandled Null pointer"

I know I shouldn't do this in my application, I'm just curious about why both glibc and system call sys_open didn't check the NULL pointer, and it actually rely on MACRO access_ok in strncpy_from_user。The calling sequence: sys_open->do_sys_open->get_name->do_getname->strncpy_from_user->access_ok->range_ok.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open, const char __user *, filename, int, flags, int, mode)
{
    long ret;

    if (force_o_largefile())
        flags |= O_LARGEFILE;

    ret = do_sys_open(AT_FDCWD, filename, flags, mode);
    /* avoid REGPARM breakage on x86: */
    asmlinkage_protect(3, ret, filename, flags, mode);
    return ret;
}

long do_sys_open(int dfd, const char __user *filename, int flags, int mode)
{
    struct open_flags op;
    int lookup = build_open_flags(flags, mode, &op);
    char *tmp = getname(filename);
    int fd = PTR_ERR(tmp);

    if (!IS_ERR(tmp)) {
            fd = get_unused_fd_flags(flags);
            if (fd >= 0) {
                    struct file *f = do_filp_open(dfd, tmp, &op, lookup);
                    if (IS_ERR(f)) {
                            put_unused_fd(fd);
                            fd = PTR_ERR(f);
                    } else {
                            fsnotify_open(f);
                            fd_install(fd, f);
                    }
            }
            putname(tmp);
    }
    return fd;
}

char *getname(const char __user * filename)
{
    return getname_flags(filename, 0, 0);
}

static int do_getname(const char __user *filename, char *page)
{
    int retval;
    unsigned long len = PATH_MAX;

    if (!segment_eq(get_fs(), KERNEL_DS)) {
            if ((unsigned long) filename >= TASK_SIZE)
                    return -EFAULT;
            if (TASK_SIZE - (unsigned long) filename < PATH_MAX)
                    len = TASK_SIZE - (unsigned long) filename;
    }

    retval = strncpy_from_user(page, filename, len);
    if (retval > 0) {
            if (retval < len)
                    return 0;
            return -ENAMETOOLONG;
    } else if (!retval)
            retval = -ENOENT;
    return retval;
}

static long
strncpy_from_user(char *dst, const char __user *src, long count)
{
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_READ, src, 1))
        return -EFAULT;
    return __strncpy_from_user(dst, src, count);
}

#define access_ok(type,addr,size)   (__range_ok(addr,size) == 0)

/* We use 33-bit arithmetic here... */
#define __range_ok(addr,size) ({ \
     unsigned long flag, roksum; \
     __chk_user_ptr(addr);   \
     __asm__("adds %1, %2, %3; sbcccs %1, %1, %0; movcc %0, #0" \
             : "=&r" (flag), "=&r" (roksum) \
             : "r" (addr), "Ir" (size), "" (current_thread_info()->addr_limit) \
             : "cc"); \
     flag; })
```

I think I should got 0 when I called __range_ok(0, 1), so everything would be fine and just got an -EFAULT error.

I can't understand the assembly in __range_ok, so I don't know why I got 1 here, anyone can help?

Thanks!!

Comment: can you clarify what this code sample has to do with `fopen` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb  It's nothing special with fopen, the system call sys_open is copied from linux standard kernel and sorted by calling sequence.

Comment: I think a simplified and more direct version of your question is simply, "Why doesn't the kernel's `__range_ok(addr, size)` macro return 0 when the `addr` is NULL?"

Comment: @indiv I think `__range_ok(addr, size)` macro should return 0 when the `addr` is NULL, but in my system, it returns 1. and additionally why glibc and system call `open` didn't check it earlier but rely on macro `__range_ok`? Is there any other possible?

Comment: @Gemini: presumably glibc doesn't check for `NULL` because it's not required to.  It's written with the assumption that it is called with a valid argument.  That's the usual 'philosophy' of C libraries.

Comment: You should know that EFAULT errors are _never_ required to be generated.  The kernel is always allowed to generate a SIGSEGV signal instead.  The scenario you describe is only a bug if the _kernel_ crashed ("panic" or "oops") on a null pointer dereference; not if the user space program crashed with a SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel code isn't always the most straightforward. `__range_ok()` has the following semantics:

```
/*
 * Test whether a block of memory is a valid user space address.
 * Returns 0 if the range is valid, nonzero otherwise.
 */
int __range_ok(unsigned long addr, unsigned long size);
```

So while you are expecting `__range_ok()` to evaluate to 0 if an access to that range would be invalid, the macro/function evaluates to non-zero in that case.